# Is there any way to swap entire tile palette, not only some tiles?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm recently working on 2D game with Unity.
I made all the prefabs of the rooms with tile map. The problem is that each rooms have 4 random concepts and all tiles' appearance should also differ depends on room's concept; for example room's appearance is same but there exist forest room, ocean room, mountain room, and cave room.

What I've tried was to make lists of all tiles and swap each tiles when room's concept is determined. But I thought it was quite inefficient that there are over 50 tiles per one concept of room, so it'll cost some memory.

So what I expect is to change entire tile palette to get the same result with it. What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

Considering all corresponding concept's tile sprites are laid out in the same location on each spritesheet, you can change its spritesheet fastly during runtime. Here's a video at the relevant time. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMCLWt1DuqI&feature=youtu.be&t=20m

You don't have to recreate tiles, their colliders etc. in this case, but only the rendered sprites.